# Invalid header signature; read 0x54535543092E4F4E, expected 0xE11AB1A1E011CFD0 - Your file appears not to be a valid OLE2 document

Tags: excel, csv, apache-poi

ok i'm posting this after so much research, all topics having similar problems didn't answer to mine. I received a .xls file to work with it (i cannot change its version) when i'm reading the file with poi i have a really strange behavior, it cannot read the original file: "Invalid header signature; read 0x54535543092E4F4E, expected 0xE11AB1A1E011CFD0 - Your file appears not to be a valid OLE2 document"
 But when i open it and save it as .xls file it works!!! It's the same file with same version, only one is the original downloaded file and the other is saved manually!! can anyone explain me this, i have to work with the original excel file.

```
File xlsFile = new File(path);
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(path);
 Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);
```

Comment: How do you read the file with POI? Show the code.

Comment: 'File xlsFile = new File(path); 
 FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(path); 
 Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);'

Comment: Use the edit button and write the code in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So guys i finally found the best solutions i guess to read and import data from my Tab-separated file using openCSV library, and it goes well for all types of CSV file (Character separated value) with titles, we have just to change the separator. Here is the code:

```
            File xlsFile = new File(path);
            CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(xlsFile), '\t');
            ArrayList<String[]> data = new ArrayList<String[]>();
            String[] nextLine;
            while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
                final int size = nextLine.length;
                //handle empty lines
                if (size == 0) {
                    continue;
                }

                String debut = nextLine[0].trim();
                if (debut.length() == 0 && size == 1) {
                    continue;
                }
                data.add(nextLine);
            }

            String[] titles = data.get(0);
            data.remove(0);

            ArrayList<Map<String, String>> mappedData = new 
            ArrayList<Map<String, String>>(data.size());

            final int titlesLength = titles.length;

            for (String[] oneData : data) {
              final Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String ();
                for (int i = 0; i < titlesLength; i++) {
                    final String key = titles[i];
                    final String value = oneData[i];
                    map.put(key, value);
                }

                mappedData.add(map);
            }
```

And then we have to get values from the mappedData by their keys(titles or columns name in my case)

Answer (score 4):

That signature looks like (the start of) tab-separated data, in reverse:

> NO.<tab>CUST

Where <tab> means the actual tab character.

If it is tab-separated data, Apache POI will not be able to use it directly.

Comment: Yes this is true, when i opened it at first it was saved as tab-separated data!  so is it like the csv, but separated with tab instead of comma?

Comment: besides, it have columns and rows, i have to import data by columns name.